# Javascript call to class method CalculateCost() does not work correctly. Not returning any information

Tags: javascript, class, methods, call

I have a class constructor called PortraitOrder(). In this constructor, I create a method called CalculateCost(). For some reason, when I make a call to that method later on in my code, nothing at all is returned. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the way I call it, the way I created it in PortraitOrder(), or the actual CalculateCost() method itself. Any and all advice/suggestions would be appreciated.

1. Here is the PortraitOrder() class with the method declaration.

   ```
      function PortraitOrder(portrait, copies, size, buyer){

                this.portrait = portrait;
                this.copies = copies;
                this.size = size;
                this.buyer = buyer;
                this.calculateCost = CalculateCost;




       }
   ```
2. Here is the CalculateCost() method which I added just below PortraitOrder()

   ```
      function CalculateCost(){

                this.size = size;

                this.copies = copies;

                var price = 0;

                if(size == "wallet"){

                     price = 10;

                }
                else if(size == "8x10"){

                     price = 10;

                }
                else if(size == "4x6"){

                     price = 10;

                }
                else if(size == "11x14"){

                     price = 30;

                }
                else{

                     price = 10;

                }

               var cost = price * copies;

               return cost;

                }
   ```
3. Finally, here is the call I make to that method. portraits is the name of the instance of the class I created earlier on in my code.

   ```
             document.write("Order cost: " + portraits.calculateCost());
   ```

Comment: because you do not use price. Read your code out loud.

Comment: Fixed it just now. Still not getting anything.

Comment: And how do you call it? Also document.write is a bad choice.

Comment: Um, `this.size = size; this.copies = copies;` is just the wrong way round. It should be `var size = this.size, copies = this.copies;`

Comment: The reason I use document.write is because its on a separate .js file, and it's writing to an html page. Also, I wrote how I called it.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is returned"? What does it print to the page? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: The JS console should tell you the error that @Bergi pointed out.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry. By nothing is returning, I mean on the html page that the call is writing to. Not getting any errors as far as I can tell. It's just that the page it is writing to will load, and nothing will be written.

Comment: @Historiun: Well, if only `portraits.calculateCost()` would return nothing, then `Order cost: ` would still be written. If not, that suggests that an error *is happening*. [Open the console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is likely throwing an exception here:

```
function CalculateCost() {

         this.size = size;  //size is unknown to interpreter here

         this.copies = copies;  //copies is unknown to interpreter here

         ...
}
```

A cleaner and more straightforward way to do everything would be this (also keep in mind, like epascarello said, that you're not using `price`):

```
function PortraitOrder(portrait, copies, size, buyer) {

         this.portrait = portrait;
         this.copies = copies;
         this.size = size;
         this.buyer = buyer;
         this.calculateCost = function() {

         var price = 0;

         if(size == "wallet"){

              price = 10;

         }
         else if(size == "8x10"){

              price = 10;

         }
         else if(size == "4x6"){

              price = 10;

         }
         else if(size == "11x14"){

              price = 30;

         }
         else{

              price = 10;

         }

        var cost = size * copies;

        return cost;

     }

}
```

Comment: I changed my code to that, and the page that I was creating with this and the rest my code simply stopped loading at all.

Comment: Wait, forget I said that. I left out a bracket. Page is displaying now. However, it returns "Order Cost: NaN"

Comment: Try changing the `var cost` line to `var cost = this.size * this.copies;`. If that doesn't work, set the debugger at that line, and see what the values of `size` and `copies` actually are.

Comment: Thats it!!! I changed size in that line to price earlier, but I changed copies to this.copies. Works great now!!!!